# Multi-class segmentation UNet gives unexpected output

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, image-segmentation

I'm trying to segment labeled objects (nuclei) using the UNet architecture in Keras and am using the Kaggle DSB18 dataset before I change to my own. To improve on the separation between two close objects, I generate a weighted map (jaidevd's implementation). I therefore end up with a input label looking like this:

[image]

Background is 0, 'real positives' are 1, spaces between objects are 2-11, depending on distance. I am trying to use a U-Net architecture as follows:

```py
# Inputs
X_train # list of all images, shaped (256, 256, 3)
Y_train # list of weighted mask, as shown above
Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes=None)

# Dice coefficient
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + 1.) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + 1.)

# Define model
inputs = Input((256, 256, 3))
s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255) (inputs)
# ... convolutional etc. layers
outputs = Conv2D(12, (1, 1), activation='softmax') (c9)
model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[dice_coef])

# Train model
ModelCheckpoint('model.hf', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
results = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=10, epochs=15, callbacks=[checkpointer])

# Test
test_image = # test image of shape (256,256,3)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
prediction = model.predict(test_image)
print(prediction.shape)
>>> (1, 256, 256, 12)
imshow(np.sum(prediction[0,:,:,1:], axis=-1)) # or argmax or a single layer
```

All of my predicted outputs are either blank or have the borders highlighted as is shown here.
[image]

Does anyone see something wrong with my code or architecture or has another idea to separate close objects? As my first project I'm having a hard time figuring out what things to look out for.

Gigantic thank you in advance. BBQuercus

Answer (score 0):

im not sure, but "outputs = Conv2D(12, (1, 1), activation='softmax') (c9)" is not the correct way. Softmax is scaling/sum your whole output to 1. 
Conclusion: Class 1 = 0.1, Class 2 = 0.001, Class 3 = 0.3 --> Sum: 1 and your results make sence. Softmax get you the probabilities for each class.

I think you can change it to "sigmoid" and hop it helps.

Best regards

*Update: Now i run into the same issues.*

Comment: I didn't end up using this method – just have borders or intersections as a second or third class. This seems to work much better. It would still be nice to figure out how the original paper did it tho.