# Unet image output borders dominating metrics and loss

Tags: image, keras, conv-neural-network, output

I am attempting to implement a pretty basic 3D UNet in keras for image to image mapping to perform denoising of medical image data but have come across a strange result when looking at my predictions. There are large streaks (a border row or column) of what I'll call saturated pixels (all 1s) which is clearly wrong - See below where left is the predicted image, middle the input and right the ground truth concatenated together so they share the same scaling (0 to 1). [Prediction, input, ground truth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13KNP.png)

The training loss is a Structural similarity index which appears to plateau during training and I suspect this could be one of the reasons why (if it's blocking off portions of the image as 1s then the loss will never be appreciably lower right?). If I crop the predictions to remove these blocks and calculate the SSIM, it increases by ~15% compared to the full image and the value itself is higher than what is recorded during training.

I am using the same generator to create the testing and training datasets so there should be no difference from input to the predict() call versus the fit() call.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119099/multi-class-segmentation-unet-gives-unexpected-output) question which is similar but it didn't have any useful solutions. I suspect it has to do with padding of the images since it's always around the borders but are there any guidelines for resolving this kind of problem? Or any ideas what this might be happening here?

Here is the code for my model (please excuse the many lines, I plan on reformatting it with functions later):

```
# make my own network (U-net) 
kernel=(3,3,3)
pool_sz = 4
input_shape = (192,192,192,1)
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

# --> Stage 1:  
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(8, kernel_size=kernel, padding='same',activation='tanh', input_shape=(input_shape))(input_layer) 
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(8, kernel_size=kernel, padding='same',activation='tanh')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
skip_layer1 = x # for use with the skip connections later

# Implement pooling
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_sz, padding="same")(x)

# --> Stage 2, increase number of kernels as we go deeper
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(16, kernel_size=kernel, padding='same',activation='tanh')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(16, kernel_size=kernel, padding='same',activation='tanh')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
skip_layer2 = x

x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_sz, padding='same')(x)
# -------- bottle neck layer --------- >

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(64, kernel_size=kernel, padding='same',activation='tanh')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(64, kernel_size=kernel, padding='same',activation='tanh')(x)
# -------------------------------------<

  # --> up convolution 2
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling3D(pool_sz)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(16, kernel_size=kernel, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=4)([x,skip_layer2])
# now actual convolutions  
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(16, kernel_size=kernel, padding='same',activation='tanh')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(16, kernel_size=kernel, padding='same',activation='tanh')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

# --> up convolution 1
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling3D(pool_sz)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(8, kernel_size=kernel, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=4)([x,skip_layer1])
# now actual convolutions 
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(8, kernel_size=kernel, padding='same',activation='tanh')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(8, kernel_size=kernel, padding='same',activation='tanh')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

# now the 1 x 1 convolution
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(1, kernel_size=(1,1,1), activation='sigmoid')(x) 

# create the model 
my_unet = tf.keras.Model(input_layer, output_layer)

def SSIM_Loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1 - tf.reduce_mean(tf.image.ssim(y_true, y_pred, 1.0))

# compile the model 
my_unet.compile(loss=SSIM_Loss, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError(), tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()]) # HP: optimizer = Adam 
# What does the finished model look like?
my_unet.summary()
```

I have tried to change the kernel size and activation functions but neither has resolved the issue so I am currently out of ideas.